# How to rotate a vector by angle if you have angle between the $\beta$ vector and the $\alpha$ vector?

Tags: vectors, angle

I am trying to rotate $\alpha$ vector CLOCKWISE so that is aligned with $\beta$ vector. I know the angle between them is $\theta = 60^⚬$. Both the magnitude of the vectors is 1.

$\begin{equation*}
\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}0.866\\0.5\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$

$\begin{equation*}
\beta = ?
\end{equation*}$

$\begin{equation*}
\theta = 60^⚬
\end{equation*}$

How can I find the vector $\beta$. If I know the angle between the vectors?

Comment: Hint:  $\frac{\sqrt3}2\approx0.866$

Comment: Alternatively, use the dot product.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: See [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) in Wikipedia. Note: this is an anti-clockwise rotation, so you should substitute $\theta = -60^\circ$ into the formula to get clockwise rotation by $60^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks Guys this is what I need.